# Remmina remoteapp over RDP

Tags: windows, rdp, remmina

I was wondering how to use remmina to open applications on a Windows machine over rdp using remoteapp (or seamless or whatever it's actually called).

I've already used Kim Knight's [RemoteApp Tool](https://sites.google.com/site/kimknight/remoteapptool) to set up remoteapp on a Windows 7 machine and I can connect and run remote apps fine from another windows box.

Allegedly FreeRDP (which Remmina uses for its RDP Plugin) has support for remoteapp. I'm not sure how to make use of it though. I can't find any examples of people actually doing this online but there is a [launchpad bug about the clipboard not working in remote apps](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1009766), from which I can infer that there is some way to run remote apps.

I've tried many combinations of settings for Client, Startup Program and Startup Path in the Advanced tab when configuring an RDP connection in Remmina, but I can't make it work. I can connect to Windows boxes with RDP just fine, just not running a remoteapp.

Comment: I found a similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/25164/seamless-remote-windows-on-linux-client -- I think it's an issue that has to be discussed at a remmina-related forum or mailing list: http://remmina.sourceforge.net/contact.shtml -- Don't forget to post a link to your forum topic there (maybe other people are interested as well)

Comment: Could one use Remmina to connect to Windows instances of Azure / Google Cloud / AWS using RDP?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, Remmina doesn't allow for RemoteApp client access. You can however do it with xfreerdp. Just use something like this on the command line:

```
xfreerdp -u   --app --plugin ./usr/local/lib/freerdp/rail.so --data "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" -- <ip of your windows machine>
```

or

```
/usr/bin/xfreerdp -u  --app --plugin rail.so --data "||" --plugin rdpdr --data printer -- <ip of your windows machine>
```

Unfortunately, sharing data between local and remote systems through clipboard is not working so it's no use to include the `--plugin cliprdr` option. I'm waiting for this issued to be addressed so that I can replace Windows for Ubuntu on 5 more users/machines!

Answer (score 3):

We use Thinomenon Linux client. It has much better RemoteApp support than freerdp. At the same time, freerdp renders windows being dragged slightly faster.

@bmullan - visit thinomenon website and learn what is their product. 
ThinRDP [thinomenon RDC application] is free. It supports full RDP7 specification. It should be clear to anyone who understands English.

Go to www.thinomenon.com and look for RDP client.

Answer (score 2):

You can try my packaged [WinConn](http://stanev.org/winconn) application.

From my website:

> WinConn simplifies creation, management and desktop integration of
>   remote windows applications in Ubuntu Linux. It uses RemoteApp
>   technology, implemented by FreeRDP project to provide seamless user
>   experience. The applications run in their own window and can be used
>   like any other locally installed Ubuntu application, without bringing
>   the full windows desktop to the user.

*installation*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:realender/winconn
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install winconn
```

Comment: Hi, how i can install on ubuntu 14.10? Because no package for this version

Answer (score 2):

When connecting to a Windows Server 2008 or later you need to have enabled the remote application on the server in:  Start - Administrative Tools - Terminal Services - TS RemoteApp Manager. In there you choose Action - Add RemoteApp Programs, and enable whichever programs you would like to make available as an RDP remote program.

All this applies to servers which are licensed for Terminal Services. If the server isn't licensed i.e. is only in remote admin mode, the remote applications options are not available.

I have found this to be the case using Remmina on Ubuntu 12.10 on my netbook.

Hope this comment isn't too late to be of use!

Answer (score 1):

Better try http://www.thinomenon.com/products/RemoteDesktopClient/linux.aspx#details

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: so Gennady.. given this is Linux and as far as I know only the FreeRDP project has gotten as far as the support for RemoteApp and RemoteFX support on a linux client... and FreeRDP is Open Source... it seems like ThinMenOn.com products are commercialized or cost $$?

Answer (score 1):

There are currently 2 ways to accomplish this (without cost).

1. The more preferred but harder way. Use FreeRDP2, the only catch with this option is that you have to be running an Enterprise, Education, or Server edition of Windows to enable remoteapp. However the performance is top notch.
2. Less preferred but incredibly easy way. After almost a week of searching I came across a program called "Winflector". I do not know if its open source or not, but im going to assume not. However for a single home user its a pretty good solution. Winflector does NOT require a special version of windows, and it does NOT use RDP. The free version allows 2 concurrent users to be connected, which is fine, in my case I only need 1. There are no functional limitations to the free version, and its incredibly easy to setup, and they even have youtube videos on how to set it up.